# How to write "Html.BeginForm" in Razor

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

If I write like this:

> form action="Images" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"

it works.

But in Razor with '@' it doesn't work. Did I make any mistakes?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, 
                             new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>

        Select a file <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

    </fieldset>
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Upload() 
{
    foreach (string file in Request.Files)
    {
        var uploadedFile = Request.Files[file];
        uploadedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/content/pics") + 
                                      Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName));
    }

    return RedirectToAction ("Upload");
}
```

Comment: Is the action actually "images" or is it "Upload/Upload"?

Comment: actually I have two controllers.
image controller with 'image' action.. and upload controller 'with upload action..

Answer (score 209, accepted):

The following code works fine:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, 
                                      new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        Select a file <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

and generates as expected:

```
<form action="/Upload/Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">    
    <fieldset>
        Select a file <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

On the other hand if you are writing this code inside the context of other server side construct such as an `if` or `foreach` you should remove the `@` before the `using`. For example:

```
@if (SomeCondition)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, 
                                      new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            Select a file <input type="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </fieldset>
    }
}
```

As far as your server side code is concerned, here's [how to proceed](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file) 
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/content/pics"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Upload");
}
```

Comment: thanks. Look at the controller I updated in my question. It doesn't work with the Razor code..

Comment: @user1076915, what does *it doesn't work mean*? Could you be a little more specific. I have updated my answer with a sample code of how your controller action could look like. If you are unable to get the uploaded file in the controller action that could mean that you have nested `<form>` tags (which is not allowed in HTML) or you might be using some javascript which hijacks the normal form submission and does an AJAX request which doesn't work with file uploads.

Comment: I used your controller action and the razor '@using'.. but it displays --> 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: @user1076915, when do you get this error message? When you want to render the upload form or when you submit the form? In the first case ensure that you have a `GET` Upload action that will serve the `Upload.cshtml` view containing this code: `public ActionResult Upload() { return View(); }`. So make sure you have a controller called `UploadController` containing the two Upload actions : one for serving the form and the other for processing the submission.

Comment: I have both of them. But I got this problem only when I submit the picture I browsed.

Comment: @user1076915, do you have some custom routes or you are using the default setup? How exactly is called your controller? Please post your full controller code.

Comment: When I upload a picture, It shows.. "The connection was reset" The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Freetalk13, the size of the file you are trying to upload. There's a default limit of 4MB which you could increase in web.config by using the `<httpRuntime>` element: `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600" executionTimeout="3600" />`.

Comment: Works, but in a POST context I suggest to add: @Html.AntiForgeryToken();