# ASP .NET RAZOR FileUpload

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to ASP.NET MVC RAZOR and I am trying to implement a File Upload to my page. I found many questions concerning this topic but I have an error and I can´t figure out why.
This is my form in my view:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />   

}
```

And this is my Controller:

```
namespace Upload.Controllers
{
    public class UploadController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Upload/

        public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);                    
                var path = Path.Combine("C:\\temp\\", fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);                
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index"); ;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my page I get an error, which says:
"Ressource not found: "/Upload".
Where is my mistake? Sorry, I know I am a beginner in ASP.NET but I read many tutorials and just want this to work.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356506/how-to-write-html-beginform-in-razor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is named `Upload`, but your action also. You'll have to use `/Upload/Upload/` as URL, or change the `Upload` actions to `Index` as the latter is the default action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I implemented the upload method in the home Controller and now it´s working fine.