# MVC5 binding action to button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have troubles with binding my button to an action. I created a form and when user click "send" button it needs to trigger some action.

Below you can see my cshtml code:

```
@model Project.Models.MailMessage    
<form name="contactForm" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div id="Contact" class="jumbotron contact-form">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h1 class="panel-title">Kontakt</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">Imie</span>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" ,placeholder ="Twoje imię"})
                            <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Imie" id="inputName" required="required">-->
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">Nazwisko</span>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Surname, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Twoje nazwisko" })
                            <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nazwisko" id="inputSurname" required="required">-->
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">Email</span>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAdress, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Adres email" })
                            <!--<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="inputEmail" required="required">-->

                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">Treść<br /> wiadomości</span>
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Treść wiadomości", id = "inputMessage", name = "inputMessage", rows="4" })
                            <!--<textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Treść wiadomości..." required="required"></textarea>-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-1">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                    Send Message
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        // GETL /Search/
        public ActionResult Search()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult SendMail(MailMessage m)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Contact");
        }
    }
```

I managed to do all this things. All code works. But stucked with I think easies part tof a job. Binding button to call  SendMail(MailMessage m) from Controller.

Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Html.BeginForm` helper and `<input type="submit" value="..." />` within. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8356569/3170952). Prefer infrastructure helpers over own HTML code where possible. You probably do not use Antiforgery mechanics to prevent CSRF attacks. It's recommended in post forms, as described in [the example](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Protect-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Applications-Using-AntiForgery-Helpers.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for suggestions BUT. Begin form destroys my code alignment. Massive parts of html code are rendered in one stream without breaking into lines.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the `action` of the form.

```
<form ... action="@Url.Action("SendMail","Home")" ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**SendMail.cshtml**

```
     @model Project.Models.MailMessage    
     <form name="contactForm" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div id="Contact" class="jumbotron contact-form">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h1 class="panel-title">Kontakt</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Imie</span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" ,placeholder ="Twoje imię"})
                        <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Imie" id="inputName" required="required">-->
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Nazwisko</span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Surname, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Twoje nazwisko" })
                        <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nazwisko" id="inputSurname" required="required">-->
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Email</span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAdress, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Adres email" })
                        <!--<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="inputEmail" required="required">-->

                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Treść<br /> wiadomości</span>
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Treść wiadomości", id = "inputMessage", name = "inputMessage", rows="4" })
                        <!--<textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Treść wiadomości..." required="required"></textarea>-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-1">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                Send Message
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Here you **controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    // GETL /Search/
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SendMail(MailMessage m)
    {
      return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendMail(MailMessage m)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Contact");
    }
}
```

When you click on button it call `[HttpPost]` Method in you controller. It is necessary to mention `[HttpPost]`

Comment: When form action look like `action=""` then how form could be post to controller and action method?

Answer (score 1):

just change your method

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SendMail(MailMessage m)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Contact");
        }
```