# MVC 4 Model Binding returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble with model binding in MVC. I have a class:

```
public class UserSurvey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
}
```

Which is the model for a view:

```
@model SurveyR.Model.UserSurvey

<form id="surveyForm">
    <div class="container survey">
        @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id)

        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Survey.Steps)
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
</form>
```

And then for the submit the controller takes a class:

```
public class SurveyResponseViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Survey Survey { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(SurveyResponseViewModel surveyResponse)
{
    ...
}
```

When I debug the submit the surveyResponse.Survey object is populated as it should be but the surveyResponse.Id value is 0 when it should be 1.

I can see the Id=1 being passed back in the submit but the model binding doesn't seem to hook it up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kev

EDIT: The rendered html looks like this:

```
<form id="surveyForm">
    <div class="container survey">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="1" />
```

So yes the value appears there and is also passed in the submit if I look using dev tools.

EDIT 2: The Form data in dev tools definitely contains "Id:1".

Comment: Is the `id` populated when you render the view? Please share the *rendered* markup.

Comment: Have you tried using Html.Begin statement? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356506/how-to-write-html-beginform-in-razor/8356569#8356569

Comment: you need to pass default list of IEnumerable Survey from your Get action of this form

Comment: How did you submit form, if your button is not `submit` button? And as noted above, it is better to use `Html.BeginForm`, but this is not necessery, of course.

Comment: The button is a submit button? Then the controller just picks up the HttpPost? I've tried Html.BeginForm now with no change.

Comment: I think this seems to be an issue of naming of fields. Okay, can you do one thing. Temporary remove the **Survey** property from the SurveyResponseViewModel class and let say add some other simple property like - public string SurveyName and do change in your view as per this and check the result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested. Its working fine.

```
    public ActionResult test1()
    {
        var model = new UserSurvey();
        model.Id = 10;
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult test1(SurveyResponseViewModel surveyResponse)
    {
        var x = surveyResponse.Id; // returns 10
        return View(new UserSurvey());
    }

    public class SurveyResponseViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Survey Survey { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserSurvey
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
    }

    public class Survey
    {
        public string Steps { get; set; }
    }

@model TestWeb.Controllers.UserSurvey

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="container survey">
        @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id)

        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Survey.Steps)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
}
```

Comment: It's not necessery to define default constructor. Classes have this constructor by default.

Comment: Oh.. how this default constructor helps in resolving above issue ??

Comment: This doesn't help I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

Your Code seems to be fine.Try passing the id value explicitly as another parameter like below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(SurveyResponseViewModel surveyResponse , int Id )
{

  surveyResponse.Id = Id
}
```

Comment: Tried this, it errors because the Id value is not passed in.

Comment: Are you using Html.Begin while rendering your view?

Comment: Id would be the same as the name attribute value of the control.So don't change the parameter name Id.

Comment: No I am calling it Id but it doesn't work still. No I am just using a form, not Html.BeginForm

Comment: I believe it would work definitely.Try to change the id as optional parameter if you are getting the error "Id value is not passed" and try.