# MVC 4: Calling action method on dropdown list select change

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dropdown list, and I want a specific action method to be called on changing selection. Here is my dropdown list:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ediFilesForm" }))
{
    var directoriesSelectList = new SelectList(Model.Directories);
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDirectory, directoriesSelectList, new {@Id = "Directories", @style = "width:Auto;height=Auto;", @size = 10, onchange = "$('#ediFilesForm').submit()", name="action:FolderChange"})
```

And here is the action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("FolderChange")]
    public ActionResult FolderChange(EdiFileModel ediFileModel)
    {
        //do your work here
        return View("Index", ediFileModel);
    }
```

For some reason, this method is never hit, but this one is hit instead:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ...
        return View(ediFileModel);
    }
```

What can I try next?

Comment: why you are passing action and controller null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First parameter of the `BeginForm` method is `Action` name, second one is the `Controller`.You are passing `null` so it uses default values.

Change your code and pass name of the `Action`  that you want to call:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FolderChange", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ediFilesForm" }))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but it is looking for MyController/FolderChange and cannot find it, of course, as it is in the same view, there is no redirection. Also, it looks like with this code, there is one action per form, does it mean that if I have 5 dropdowns, I need a form for each?

Comment: @DavidShochet pass the controller name without the Controller suffix. and yes you need different form for each dropdown or, use jquery/ajax and send a request to actions instead of submiting the form on selection change.if you don't know how to do it search : _populating dropdown with ajax in mvc_ on google and you will find plenty of resources

Comment: Thanks, it worked. May I also ask you a question? I have on this form several buttons, and each has its own action method. They all are in the same form, and yet work perfectly. Why don't they need a form each?

Answer (score 1):

try below code :-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FolderChange", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ediFilesForm" }))
{
////your code
}
```

the problem occurs because you are not passing enough information in beginform.

for more information :-

[How to write "Html.BeginForm" in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356506/how-to-write-html-beginform-in-razor)