# HttpPost is not being called after click on Save Button in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Below is my code in my .cshtml and have two buttons but i am not able to call my action method by clicking on any of the button.

```
    @model IList<ClaimBuildMVC.ClaimBuildBE.ManageUsersBE>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "GetEditRecord";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="Content-inner-pages">
<div class="Accountsettings">
    <h2><span>Edit User Details</span></h2>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-content">
            <div class="form-horizontal form-details">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 control-label">First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-4">                            
                        @Html.TextBox("FirstName",   (string)ViewBag.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "FirstName" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-4">                            
                        @Html.TextBox("LastName",(string)ViewBag.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "LastName" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 control-label">Role</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-4">                            
                        @Html.TextBox("RoleName",(string)ViewBag.FkRoleId,
                       new { @class = "form-control", @id = "RoleName" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 control-label">Status</label>
                   <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-4">                           
                            @Html.DropDownList("Status", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem{ Text="Active", Value = "0" },             new SelectListItem{ Text="InActive", Value = "1" }
             }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>                   
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-offset-4">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" name="actiontype" class="btn-class btn-success">
                        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" name="actiontype" class="btn-class btn-danger">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my Controller

```
    [HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult GetEditRecord(ManageUsersBE MU,string actiontype)         
    {
        if (actiontype == "Save")
        {
my logic

        }
        return View("ManageUsersBE");
    }
```

so when i click on save button even after putting debugger on my controller, it is not calling to that controller.Am i misiing something.Please help

Comment: Wrap your HTML inside a form, use either plain HTMl or Html.Begin form from razor

Comment: @Reddy can you just give me example.i am very much new to MVC

Comment: Yes done, have a check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap up your from elements inside a form only then you will be able to post.

**Using Razor Syntax**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ACtionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal form-details">
     .....
   </div>
}
```

---

**Using Plain HTML**

```
<form action="/ControllerName/ActionName" method="post">    
    <div class="form-horizontal form-details">
         .....
    </div>
</form>
```

Also take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8356569/2592042

Answer (score 1):

You should use form tag to make HTTPPost work.

in razor use

```
  @using(html.beginform())
    {
     //your html
    }
```

In simple HTML you can do it as

```
<form method="post">
 //your html
</form>
```