# MVC - Redirect to view after "$.post" to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On the click of a button:

```
$("#newSave").click(function () {
    AddNewAccount();
});
```

I am making a function call to:

```
function AddNewAccount() {
    $.post("/RxCard/AddAccount",
        {
            NewAccountName: $("#newAccountName").val(),
            NewAccountAddress: $("#newAccountAddress").val(),
            NewAccountCity: $("#newAccountCity").val(),
            NewAccountState: $("#newAccountState").val(),
            NewAccountZip: $("#newAccountZip").val(),
            NewAccountArea: $("#newArea").val(),
            NewAccountPrefix: $("#newPrefix").val(),
            NewAccountSuffix:$("#newSuffix").val()

        }, function (errorMsg) {
            if (errorMsg.length > 0) {
                $('div#divSearchList').empty();
                $('div#divSearchList').html(errorMsg);
            }
            else {
                loadAccount(accountId, false);
            }
    });
    $("body").css("cursor", "default").delay(1000);
}
```

from there the data is passed into the controller action:

```
public ActionResult AddAccount(string NewAccountName, string NewAccountAddress, string NewAccountCity, string NewAccountState, string NewAccountZip, string NewAccountArea, string NewAccountPrefix, string NewAccountSuffix)
{
     DuplicatesPage model = GetDups(NewAccountName, NewAccountAddress, NewAccountCity, NewAccountState, NewAccountZip, NewAccountArea, NewAccountPrefix, NewAccountSuffix);
     return RedirectToAction("DuplicatePage", model);
}
```

in order to generate the model (for the view i am attempting to display) from:

```
private DuplicatesPage GetDups(string NewAccountName, string NewAccountAddress, string NewAccountCity, string NewAccountState, string NewAccountZip, string NewAccountArea, string NewAccountPrefix, string NewAccountSuffix)
{

    DuplicatesPage model = new DuplicatesPage();
    duplicates results = new duplicates();
    var phone = NewAccountPrefix.ToString() + NewAccountSuffix.ToString();
    var datenow = DateTime.Now;
    var firstofmonth = new DateTime(datenow.Year, datenow.Month, 1);

    OdbcCommand cmd1 = new OdbcCommand();

    cmd1.CommandText = "{call dbo.Maint_AddClinic(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", NewAccountName);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", NewAccountAddress);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", NewAccountCity);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", NewAccountState);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", NewAccountZip);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaCode", NewAccountArea);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", phone);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", firstofmonth);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountTypeID", 2);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IgnoreDupAddress", 1);
    DataTable dt = GetData(cmd1);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        Pharmacy pharmacy = new Pharmacy();
        pharmacy.AccountName = row["AccountName"].ToString();
        pharmacy.Address = row["Address"].ToString();
        pharmacy.City = row["City"].ToString();
        pharmacy.ZipCode = row["ZipCode"].ToString();
        results.Pharmacies.Add(pharmacy);
    }
    results.Count = dt.Rows.Count;
    model.DupResults = results;
    return model;
}
```

and end at:

```
public ActionResult DuplicatePage()
{
     return View("Duplicates");
}
```

The problem is that I am not redirected to the view `Duplicates`. I just stay on the same page. The problem is probably obvious but I cant seem to locate it. I tried redirecting after making the call to `AddNewAccount` on the button click but my model for `Duplicates` is not generated at that time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `RedirectToAction` with an `AJAX` call and that will never work because the `RedirectToAction` will return a redirect response `HTTP 302` to your `AJAX` call, and your `AJAX` call will not consume this response as you expect, and no redirects will ever happen.

To fix this you need to change your `$.post` to a full post back, or send the `url` to redirect to with a response and do the redirect manually on the client side and then for example use: `window.location.href = 'new-url-to-go-to';`

Comment: Do you know any good articles on how to do postbacks? I'm not all that familiar with them.

Comment: I am not seeing your `HTML` but I can guess that those are a set of fields you fill data with, if this is the case then just put them in a form and make it a postable form using `@Html.BeginForm` like mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356506/how-to-write-html-beginform-in-razor)