# ASP.NET MVC Web Application - My enquiry page isn't sending to my DB when I hit submit, I can't see why

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I am in the process of creating a web application for a class in school using ASP.NET MVC. For my DB, I am using Entity Framework - code first. I have a very simple enquiry page that asks for; Name, Email, Subject & Message. When filled out and the submit button is pressed, it should insert into my DB table but all it does is clears the form. I will show my code below, if someone could point out why it isn't sending to my DB table, that would be great! Thanks in advance :)

Here is also a screenshot showing the Enquiry table, if that helps;
[image: DBTables]

ModelContext -

```
namespace SDP_Project.DAL
{
public class SDP_ProjectContext:DbContext

{
    public SDP_ProjectContext() : base("SDP_Project")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<TripType> TripTypes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CustomerOrder> CustomerOrders { get; set; }

    public DbSet<OrderedProduct> Orderedproducts { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Enquiry> Enquiries { get; set; }

}
}
```

EnquiryController -

```
using System;  
using SDP_Project.ViewModels;
using SDP_Project.Models;   
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SDP_Project.Controllers
{
public class EnquiryController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Enquiry vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            EnquiryAdd enquiryAdd = new EnquiryAdd();
            try
            {
                enquiryAdd.Add(vm);
                ModelState.Clear();
                ViewBag.Message = "Thank you for Contacting us ";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                ViewBag.Message = $" Sorry we are facing Problem here {ex.Message}";
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

Enquiry ViewModel -

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace SDP_Project.ViewModels
{
public class Enquiry
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
}
```

EnquiryAdd Model -

```
using SDP_Project.DAL;
using SDP_Project.ViewModels;

namespace SDP_Project.Models
{
public class EnquiryAdd
{
    SDP_ProjectContext db = new SDP_ProjectContext();

    public void Add(Enquiry newEnquiry)
    {
        SDP_Project.ViewModels.Enquiry enquiry = new  SDP_Project.ViewModels.Enquiry();
        enquiry.Name = newEnquiry.Email;
        enquiry.Email = newEnquiry.Name;
        enquiry.Subject = newEnquiry.Subject;
        enquiry.Message = newEnquiry.Message;

        db.Enquiries.Add(enquiry);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
}
```

Enquiry View -

```
@model SDP_Project.ViewModels.Enquiry

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-   unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div>
        @if (ViewBag.Message == null)
        {
        <div>
            <form method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                    <label asp-for="Name">Name</label>
                    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name"
                          class="text-muted"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Email">Email</label>
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email"
                          class="text-muted"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Subject">Subject</label>
                    <input asp-for="Subject" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Subject"
                          class="text-muted"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Message">Message</label>
                    <textarea rows="5" cols="15"
                              asp-for="Message" class="form-control">    </textarea>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Message"
                          class="text-muted"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit"
                            class="btn btn-success">
                        Send
                    </button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        }
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
        <div>@ViewBag.Message</div>


            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: have you tried debugging the add method and see if any exceptions are coming?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I tried putting breakpoints on the add method and it doesn't even trigger the breakpoints lol, i'm so confused!

Comment: Try changing `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">` with `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>`

Comment: you haven't specified the controller and action to which form should be posted, your `form` tag should be like : `<form asp-controller="Enquiry" 
      asp-action="Index" method="post">`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I tried both yours and Berkays advice, but it doesn't change. It clears the form but doesn't send it to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this][1].

[1]: [How to write "Html.BeginForm" in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356506/how-to-write-html-beginform-in-razor). Try creating the form with the MVC helper setting the right controller and action