# How do I assign my post method to my button in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I have the following code on my controller(ItemController).

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LikeIncrement(VoteItem voteItem)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (MoraleCheckerDBEntities1 dc = new MoraleCheckerDBEntities1())
            {
                var currentItem = dc.VoteItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == voteItem.Id);
                currentItem.ThumbsUp = voteItem.ThumbsUp++;
                currentItem.ThumbsDown = voteItem.ThumbsDown + 0;
                dc.SaveChanges();                   
            }

        }
        return View(voteItem);
    }
```

then I have this button on my View

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="dislike-btn" >
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
 </button>
```

I want everytime a user clicks this button to call that method.
Please.

Comment: Either make a normal form submit and redirect back to the same page, or better use ajax to make the post so that you stay on the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to insert your button into a form element linked, with post method, to the action:

```
<form method="POST" action="Controller/LinkItem">
 ...form data elements ...
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="dislike-btn" >
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
 </button>
</form>
```

Or you can use ajax linking button to their action:

```
$('#dislike-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var optionalData = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
  $.post('Controller/LinkItem', optionalData, function(response) {
    // do something to your controller, you should return a JSON object.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimal you can do:

**jQuery**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#dislike-btn').on('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("LikeIncrement", "Item")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {voteItem: 'some data'},
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, status) {
                    // error handler
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    alert('fail' + status);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

**View**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="dislike-btn" >
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
 </button>
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LikeIncrement(VoteItem voteItem)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (MoraleCheckerDBEntities1 dc = new MoraleCheckerDBEntities1())
            {
                var currentItem = dc.VoteItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == voteItem.Id);
                currentItem.ThumbsUp = voteItem.ThumbsUp++;
                currentItem.ThumbsDown = voteItem.ThumbsDown + 0;
                dc.SaveChanges();                   
            }

        }
        return View(voteItem);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use Form tag and use submit button, like this:

```
<form action="/LikeIncrement" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and for input model (VoteItem), you should use Input with Name property, like this:

[HTML form Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp)

for MVC [BeginForm in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356506/how-to-write-html-beginform-in-razor)

I hope help you.