# Error when uploading file: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type Document is not part of the model for the current context.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting below error when trying to upload a file to a folder:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type Document is not
>   part of the model for the current context.'

Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult AddHRDocument()
{
    DocumentsConn db = new DocumentsConn();
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddHRDocument(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    //Extract Image File Name.
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

    //Set the Image File Path.
    string filePath = "~/Documents/HR/" + fileName;

    //Save the Image File in Folder.
    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));

    //Insert the Image File details in Table.
    DocumentsConn db = new DocumentsConn();
    db.Documents.Add(new Document
    {
        DocumentName = fileName,
        Document_url = filePath

    });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form for uploading the file?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code for upload multi files.you can edit your code for 0ne file.

**View** : Write `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControolerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

**UploadFile Box:**

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Files, new { type = "file", name = "Files", multiple = "multiple", @class = "form-control", accept = "image/*" })
```

use below code in your action for get files from request:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult UploadFile(long Id)
```

action input parameter not necessary **HttpPostedFileBase** .

```
                  for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var file = Request.Files[i];                             

                        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)?.ToLower();

                        string path = Server.MapPath("~") + "Files\\UploadImages\\" + fileName;

                        //TODO: Fill Properties Table.example: DocType Or Id Or AddressFile
                       // entity.DocType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName)?.ToLower();

                        if (File.DocType?.ToLower() == ".png" || File.DocType?.ToLower() == ".img"
                                                                || File.DocType?.ToLower() == ".jpeg"
                                                                || File.DocType?.ToLower() == ".jpg")
                        {                              
                            file.SaveAs(path);
                            //TODO: Save Info File In Database
                        }
```

Comment: help link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356506/how-to-write-html-beginform-in-razor

Answer (score 0):

This error is very generic, it could have a number of reasons.

1-The problem may be in the connection string. Ensure your connection
   string is for `SqlClient` provider, with no metadata stuff related to
   `EntityFramework`.

2-Make sure that you are not explicitly ignoring the type:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Ignore<Document>();
}
```

3-There is a problem with naming to map entity to table name:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Doucment>().ToTable("Doucment");
}
```