# ASP.NET C# - Unable to upload image

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to upload an image by form in ASP.NET

This is my model

```
    public class ItemTypeModels
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ItemTypeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public CategoryModels models { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ItemTypeName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ItemTypeImageName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Create Page

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","ItemTypeModels",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  {
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ItemTypeModels</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryID, "CategoryID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemTypeName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ItemTypeName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemTypeName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemTypeImageName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="UploadedFile" required />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

And finally, this is my POST Method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ItemTypeID,CategoryID,ItemTypeName,ItemTypeImageName")] ItemTypeModels itemTypeModels)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(itemTypeModels.UploadedFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(itemTypeModels.UploadedFile.FileName);
            fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
            itemTypeModels.ItemTypeImageName = "~/Image/" + fileName;
            fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), fileName);
            itemTypeModels.UploadedFile.SaveAs(fileName);
            db.ItemTypeModels.Add(itemTypeModels);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categorymodels, "CategoryID", "CategoryName", itemTypeModels.CategoryID);
        return View(itemTypeModels);
    }
```

Whenever I press the Create button on the Create page, the fields (Category + Name) stay filled, however the image uploader gets reset and states no file chosen. I did follow the tutorial that I used properly, so i'm not sure as to why the issue is having, I have also created the folder that the image is meant to be saved in. When I check the database, the data isn't being saved either.

Comment: please see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56713203/5576498

Answer (score -1):

Refer This link [How to Upload Files in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.aurigma.com/upload-suite/developers/aspnet-mvc/how-to-upload-files-in-aspnet-mvc)

your action method must accept **HttpPostedFileBase**:

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) 
{
  // your code
}
```