# Rewrite Model from View on Submit C# ASP.NET reload page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, http-post

I'm trying to post information to my Model from my View in order to change the information it's displayed on it. I'll explain really quick what I mean.

So I have this model called ModelGetInformation.cs that gets information from an URL and I parse the URL information into a dataset or ds right, ok so in order for me to query this URL with different data I must submit information from my VIEW into my MODEL sorry for caps just wanted to be sure it's all clear :p so moving on.

```
            namespace Project.Models
            {
                public class ModelGetInformation
                {
                    public string date_ini { get; set; }
                    public string date_fin { get; set; }


                    public System.Data.DataSet loadInformation() //This is the default query it's done and shown to the user, query last 3 days until today

                    {
                        string date_ini = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3).ToString("MM.dd.yy");
                        string date_fin = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM.dd.yy");
                        string sURL = ("myurl.com/myTable.html?date_ini= " + date_ini + "&date_fin= " + date_fin + "&");
                        DataSet ds = clsUtils.GetDSInterface(sURL); // This makes a dataset out of the url
                        return ds;
                    }
                    public System.Data.DataSet reloadInformation() // This is supposed to be the submitted Model information to be displayed
                    {
                        date_ini.ToString();
                        date_fin.ToString();
                        string sURL = ("myurl.com/myTable.html?date_ini= " + date_ini + "&date_fin= " + date_fin + "&");
                        DataSet ds = clsUtils.GetDSInterface(sURL);
                        return ds;
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is my controller HomeController.cs

```
                namespace Project.Controllers
                {
                    public class HomeController : Controller
                    {
                        public ActionResult Index()
                        {
                            return View();
                        }
                        public ActionResult Test()
                        {
                            Project.Models.ModelGetInformation modelGetInformation = new Models.ModelGetInformation();
                            return View(modelGetInformation);
                        }

                        [HttpPost]
                            public ActionResult Test(ModelGetInformation parametros)
                                {
                                    string date_ini = parametros.date_ini;
                                    string date_fin = parametros.date_fin;
                                return View(parametros);
                                }
                    }
                }
```

And this is my view Test.cshtml

```
                @{

                }
                    <div class="container-fluid">

                        @model Project.Models.ModelGetInformation
                        System.Data.DataSet ds_loadInformation = Model.loadInformation();
                        System.Data.DataTable dt_FirstTable = ds_loadInformation.Tables[2];
                        System.Data.DataTable dt_SecondTable = ds_loadInformation.Tables[1];


                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="2" align="center">Pick start and finish date</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Date start: </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.date_ini)
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Date Finish: </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.date_fin)
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        }





                    <!-- Table -->
                                <div class="card-body">

                                    <!-- Table -->

                                    <div class="table-striped">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                            <thead align="center">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Col1</th>
                                                    <th>Col2</th>
                                                    <th>Col3</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody id="mydataTable">
                                                @{

                                                        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt_FirstTable.Rows)
                                                        {
                                                            string value1 = dr["value1"].ToString();
                                                            string value2 = dr["value2"].ToString();
                                                            string value3 = dr["date"].ToString();

                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="center">@value1</td>
                                                                <td align="center">@value2</td>
                                                                <td align="center">@date</td>
                                                        }
                                                     }
                                                </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                    </div>
```

How can I make this submit post send the date from my View into my Model and request again the URL with the parameters I added in my post form to get new results in my datatable???

Thanks in advance sorry if there's any mistakes :(

Comment: I think you are confusing an HTML table and a DataTable. A data table represents a series of rows called DataRows. Unless you intend to use Ajax, and get the response back and parse it out on the front end, I would recommend using the default MVC model binding. Take a look at this [article](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-HtmlBeginForm-Tutorial-with-example.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write "Html.BeginForm" in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356506/how-to-write-html-beginform-in-razor)